# What are the problems with small sample size based predictions when using time-series data?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, survival, small-sample

I had to put the majority of the question in the textbox as Cross Validated didn't like the fact my question was too long....but here it is, in terms of what I wanted to ask:

Due to a small sample size (i.e. large earthquakes are rare), does predicting 'post-large earthquake aftershocks' suffer from the same statistical problems of predicting the actual earthquake itself?

or

Does the consistency (assuming there is some) of 'post-large earthquake aftershock' effect make it valid to make 'strong' (with high probability of success) and accurate predictions about when/where and how large these aftershocks might be?

And finally are the statistical techniques different for predicting 'post-(rare) event events' vs predicting the actual (rare) event itself?

Any thoughts, links or pointers would be much appreciated.

P.S.
This question is partially related to my previous question [Can survival analysis be used to predict earthquakes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/can-survival-analysis-be-used-to-predict-earthquakes)

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy of prediction depends on the variance of the estimate.  For averages of iid observations that variance goes down by 1/√n.  So in general for iid observations the accuracy of an estimate improves as the sample size increases (not necessarily exactly by 1/√n).  Now in you case you have a point process and events may be correlated, certainly aftershocks from the same quake will be highly correlated.  When observations are positively correlated the variance does not decrease as rapidly with increasing sample size as it does for iid observations.  So small sample size and correlation make it difficult to make accurate predictions.  However, if the individual observations have a very low variance, imrovement may not be necessary.

So the short and sweet of it is small sample size along with correlation and a large variance for the individual observstions leads to poor prediction.  But if the variance of the individual observations is small, the small sample size and correlation may not be important and accurate prediction is possible.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with the correlation to help improve accuracy?

Comment: If successive observations are negatively correlated the variance of the sum is less than the sum of the variances and the variance goes down faster than for iid observations.  That is like the old saying that errors tend to cancel each other out.  it is not really true when observations are independent but it is the case for negatively correlated observations.  That is because if one observation is high relative to the mean the next observation is likely to be small relative to the mean, a consequence of the negative correlation.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the size of Earthquakes followed a power law distribution, and if you used the same distribution to model aftershocks, then they would not be bound to be smaller than the original earthquake.

I'm not a seismologist, but I think that aftershocks are defined to be smaller than the main shock.  So I'd expect that you could probably fit a (non power law) distribution for aftershock size (with a measurable variance), and that this should not have the rare extreme values associated with the power law distribution.